# perl one liner to replace part of file with other file

Tags: perl

I'm having problems with this one liner:

```
perl -pe 's/FINDME/`cat rep.txt`/ge' in.txt
```

If i use it exactly like this, it works, but I also want to add some text before and after the replaced content:

```
perl -pe 's/FINDME/SOMETHING1`cat rep.txt`SOMETHING2/ge' in.txt
```

I get the error:

```
syntax error at -e line 1, near "SOMETHING1`cat rep.txt`"
```

Shouldn't the output of the command be treated like a string?

Adicionally, I'm also confused by the fact I can't replace to something with the character <

```
perl -pe 's/SOMETHING/<SOMETHINGELSE/ge' in.txt
Unterminated <> operator at -e line 1.
```

Escaping the < (\<) gives me the same error.

Comment: Which version of Perl are you using?  My 5.10 says: [sshi052@lstappdev01 ~]$ perl -pe 's/FINDME/SOMETHING`cat rep.txt`/ge' in.txt
Backticks found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "SOMETHING`cat rep.txt`"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "SOMETHING`cat rep.txt`"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/FINDME/SOMETHING`cat rep.txt`/ge"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Also, the 's/SOMETHING/<ELSE/ge' works fine for me.  You may have an older Perl version?  Try 's/SOMETHING/\<ELSE/ge' (with a backstroke to escape the '<')

Comment: Thanks for the comments. My installed version is v5.18.2. I did try escaping the < with backstroke, but got the same error.

Comment: See my answer below... and while /<ELSE/ worked for me without error, it didnt actually do the replace, because of course <ELSE evaluates to null string....

Comment: @SteveShipway: I don't know how you got `s/SOMETHING/<ELSE/ge` to run without complaint as `<ELSE` isn't a valid Perl expression. I also don't see why it *'of course'* evaluates to a null string, and even if it did it the substitution should replace `SOMETHING` with that null string. I think you can't have been running the code you thought you were

Comment: @Borodin - Looking back on what I wrote I'm not sure what I was doing either.  Possibly 's/SOMETHING/<ELSE>/ge' which runs and evaluates to null.  The final answer I gave below is coherent and correct, though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `e` modifier to the regexp, which means to eval{} (or in other words, execute) the replacement string as a code snippet, but you are treating it like a shell replacement.  The `e` modifier expects CODE, not TEXT.

So, a normal (global) replace would use:

```
s/FINDME/REPLACE/g
```

... and this is fine.  However, when you use an `e` flag, the replacement is run as code.  Thus:

```
s/FINDME/`cat foo.txt`/ge;
```

... is equivalent to ...

```
$replace = `cat foo.txt`;
s/FINDME/$replace/g;
```

So, you can see how this:

```
s/FINDME/SOMETHING`cat foo.txt`/ge;
```

... is equivalent to...

```
$replace = SOMETHING`cat foo.txt`;
s/FINDME/$replace/g;
```

... and this is clearly a syntax error.  Try this way instead:

```
s/FINDME/"SOMETHING".`cat foo.txt`/ge;
```

and you will find that it works, because this is valid code:

```
$replace = "SOMETHING".`cat foo.txt`;
```

( You can of course put even more complex things in there; since what is going on behind the scenes is an eval{}, your code is actually doing this:

```
eval { "SOMETHING".`cat foo.txt`; }
s/FINDME/$_/g;
```

however I'm simplifying for ease of comprehension :-)